# Sort Knockout's computed only once in data-bind foreach

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

so here my problem is that I want knockout's foreach to display my computed array of objects in descending order according to one value per object (totalTTC of Order). And I dont want this order to change even if the totalTTC in an order change when user change stuff. But the sorting is updating each time a change is made and I dont know how to disable this. Here is my computed:

```
appViewModel.orders = ko.computed(() -> (
  orders = []
  # Check if seller of this shoppingCartLine exists
  appViewModel.shoppingCartLines().forEach((shoppingCartLine) ->
  existingOrder = null
  orders.forEach((order) ->
    if order.seller? and order.seller.id() == shoppingCartLine.ad.ownerJson.id()
      existingOrder = order
  )
  # If it exits add it to its shoppingCartLines array
  if existingOrder?
    existingOrder.shoppingCartLines.push(shoppingCartLine)
    return
  # Otherwise create a new order from this shoppingCartLine
  else
    seller = shoppingCartLine.ad.ownerJson
    shoppingCartLines = ko.observableArray([shoppingCartLine])

    order = new Order(seller, shoppingCartLines, appViewModel.freeShippingFeesThreshold)
    orders.push(order)
    return
  )
  return orders
))
```

And here is my html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: orders().sort(function (o, r) { return r.totalHT() > o.totalHT() ? 1 : -1 }), as: 'order'}">
```

I just want the sorting function to be triggered once.

Comment: Do you knockout foreach to update when orders are add/removed?  If not, you can probably just not use an observable for this.

Comment: How could I do that ?

Comment: Just take the sort function out of the binding and call it manually once after the array is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you do not need knockout to update when orders are add/removed, and don't need to update the sorting, orders does not need to be an observable.

Personally I'd also sort it in the viewModel.  I like the markup to contain as little code as possible.

```
  appViewModel.orders = computeOrders().sort(function (o, r) { return r.totalHT() > o.totalHT() ? 1 : -1 });

  function computeOrders() {
      # Check if seller of this shoppingCartLine exists
      appViewModel.shoppingCartLines().forEach((shoppingCartLine) ->
      existingOrder = null
      orders.forEach((order) ->
        if order.seller? and order.seller.id() == shoppingCartLine.ad.ownerJson.id()
          existingOrder = order
      )
      # If it exits add it to its shoppingCartLines array
      if existingOrder?
        existingOrder.shoppingCartLines.push(shoppingCartLine)
        return
      # Otherwise create a new order from this shoppingCartLine
      else
        seller = shoppingCartLine.ad.ownerJson
        shoppingCartLines = ko.observableArray([shoppingCartLine])

        order = new Order(seller, shoppingCartLines, appViewModel.freeShippingFeesThreshold)
        orders.push(order)
        return
      )
      return orders
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: orders">
```

Comment: I've tried that but it's not working. It's not my code initially. I'm just adding some change to an existing code at work and apparently it have to stay a knockout observable otherwise it keeps throwing me errors at compilation.

Comment: try to keep it observable, not computed. This should not generate errors and will not re-sort the array: `appViewModel.orders = ko.observable(computeOrders().sort(function (o, r) { return r.totalHT() > o.totalHT() ? 1 : -1 }));`